# Firefox addon "keyconfig" seems to be unique... But why isn't it in Firefox's repository?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions

I recently tried out an addon called "keyconfig", and it is ideal for what I want.
It re-binds Firefox's shortcut-keys.
I've not found any other way to do this.

This addon has a public forum of 1739 posts on  [forums.mozillazine.org](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994)
This seems to be a well known add-on, and it worked for me in an Ubuntu VM.

Does anyone know why this add-on is **not** listed on Firefox's own [**official** Add-ons page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/)?
(Is it buggy? Is it safe? ...)
It is available as `"keyconfig 20080929"` at [mozilla.dorando.at](http://mozilla.dorando.at/readme.html)

And I almost forgot... Is there any other way to customize Firefox' keyboard-shortcuts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was asked in 2010, the [source](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/09/07/customize-shortcuts-firefox-keyconfig-alternative/) was from 2011, the answer is here, in 2014. XD

> Keyconfig is still being developed, despite that it is not available
>   in the Mozilla Firefox add-on repository.

I almost forgot too. There are Vimperator, Pendatactyl (you may know all of them). However, there is a new competitor just have appeared some month ago and I really like it. It's VimFx. Because it's new, then it's lack of powerful of Vimperator.